# Twilio Voice URL

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

The Twilio documentation shows the demo Voice URL as - http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml
e.g.

```
Call call = Call.creator(new PhoneNumber(to), new PhoneNumber(from),
new URI("http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml")).create();
```

But what is the actual URL. I have subscription and can see Account SID and Auth token listed but could not locate the URL. If anybody know how to locate the actual URL, please share.

Thanks

I tried locating the URL in the Twilio account but could not find one.